# Error al llamar función con c# con parámetro opcional

Tags: c#, function

Estoy intentando llamar a la siguiente función:

```
public void seleccionarpanelsecundario([Optional, DefaultParameterValue(null)] ref TabPage a, [Optional, DefaultParameterValue(false)]  bool regresaralpaneldeterminado) // cambia el panel secundario a travez de tabitem
        {
```

Y lo que quiero hacer es llamarla solo el segundo parámetro. De la siguiente forma:

```
seleccionarpanelsecundario(, true);
```

y me dice que falta un argumento, pero es opcional.

En otro caso intento llamar a una funcion donde evio tambien un parametro, del cual es opcional de la siguiente manera. Tengo la siguiente funcion:

```
 public string rellenarlistadetickets(string iniciofecha, string finfecha, [Optional, DefaultParameterValue(0)] ref decimal total, bool obtenerdecajaabierta = false)
        {
```

Y la llamo de la siguiente forma y tambien me da error:

```
console.writeline(ticketaanular.rellenarlistadetickets(desde.Text, desde.Text, obtenerdecajaabierta: true))
```

en este último me dice el siguiente cartel:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo lograr lo que estoy tratando de hacer, llamar a una función evitando un parámetro opcional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos caso a caso...

En el primer caso, por supuesto que es opcional...

Pero como todos los parametros son opcionales, el compilador esta infiriendo que lo tuyo es un error. Se equivoca, no te confundiste, pero como puede saberlo?

Si queres llamarlo solo con el segundo parametro, o mandas el primero con su valor por defecto.. o le pasas parametros con nombre.(nombredelparametro: valor)

```
seleccionarpanelsecundario(regresaralpaneldeterminado: true);
```

En el segundo caso, los ultimos dos parametros son opcionales. (nota: no se que se define asi:  [Optional, DefaultParameterValue(0)]). Al poner parametro = valor, ya lo estas declarando opcional.

Pero.. como no entiendo esa forma de definir parametros opcionales, parece que el compilador tampoco, porque al mostrar la firma de la funcion, no aparece como opcional. Por eso no podes llamar al ultimo posicionalmente, porque te falta un parametro formal de la funcion...